# SMD - identify two parts

Tags: capacitor, surface-mount

I think one is a 10uf capacitor 10-20l.

Second one no idea.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Google suggests the top one is 10uF @20V. Don't you have a multimeter to test these? Could either be tant caps or diodes. Impossible to know just by looking at them.

Answer (score 0):

Second one looks like a [47uF, 10V capacitor](https://www.vishay.com/doc?40180)